# SQL - COUNT e GROUP BY duvida

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou com a seguinte questão:

> Selecione o primeiro nome (first_name) e o título do filme (film) de todos(as) os/as atores/atrizes (actor) associados(as) aos filmes da categoria (category) comédia (Comedy) (usar IN ou ANY).

Até o momento consegui isto:

```
SELECT first_name, title, COUNT(*)

FROM ACTOR a, CATEGORY c, FILM f, FILM_CATEGORY fc, FILM_ACTOR fa

WHERE a.actor_id = fa.actor_id

AND fa.film_id = c.name in (‘Comedy’)

GROUP BY c.name;
```

O problema é que não mostra nada. Ele alega perda na conexão com o SQL, mas sei que é algum erro no código, já tentei varias formas mas não consegui.

Imagem do diagrama:
[image: Diagrma da questao]

Comment: esse é um problema simples e acredito que muitos usuários do SO podem responder a query completa sem problemas, mas já que esse é um exercício, acredito que valha a pena você estudar como resolver ao invés de um usuário daqui te dar a resposta de mão beijada, pelo que to vendo aqui você precisa só saber o funcionamento de JOIN e de IN nesse exercício, acredito que só de você ler sobre você já vai conseguir responder e aprender direitinho :)

JOIN - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

IN - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Answer (score -4):

Link para referencias:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_in

```
INNER JOIN Customers  on Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
WHERE Customers.Country  IN ('Brazil', 'Argentina', 'Portugal')
GROUP BY Customers.Country;
```

Seu código:

```
SELECT first_name, title, COUNT(*)

FROM ACTOR a, CATEGORY c, FILM f, FILM_CATEGORY fc, FILM_ACTOR fa

WHERE a.actor_id = fa.actor_id

AND fa.film_id = c.name in (‘Comedy’)

GROUP BY c.name;
```

alguns apontamentos.

o total **COUNT(*)** é necessário?

aqui **fa.film_id = c.name** está comparando  id com o nome da categoria,
acredito que seria **fa.film_id = c.categoria_id**

```
SELECT first_name, title, **COUNT(*)**

FROM ACTOR a, CATEGORY c, FILM f, FILM_CATEGORY fc, FILM_ACTOR fa

WHERE a.actor_id = fa.actor_id

AND **fa.film_id = c.name** in (‘Comedy’)

GROUP BY c.name;
```

Comment: essa resposta não responde a pergunta...

Comment: Fiz as devidas alterações, mas veja só
Ele até roda, mas me retorna apenas um nome e apenas um titulo, porém esse titulo, no caso esse filme, nem da categoria "Comedy" é. Já olhei as tabelas atores e filmes, ele teria de me retornar vários atores e vários filmes, que são relacionados a "Comedy"

Comment: pode colocar os dados das tabelas aqui para ver